# Passing a function as prop - TypeError:functionname is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I'm trying to pass a function as a prop to be used in another function, but I'm getting the following error.

> TypeError: handleFunction is not a function

I have the component in a separate file where the component is called

TestComponent.tsx

```
function TestComponent(handleFunction: any, input: any) {
  return (
    <FormSpy subscription={{ dirty: true, values: true }}>
      {() => (
        <OnChange name="item-name">
          {async (value) => {
            handleFunction(input.onChange, value);
          }}
        </OnChange>
      )}
    </FormSpy>
  );
}

export default TestComponent;
```

This file is imported into this component

```
import TestComponent from 'components/TestComponent';

<List
  Test={TestComponent}
/>
```

List.tsx then renders that component and passes the function as a prop

```
function List({ Test }) {
  function handlePrimaryFunction(
    onChange: (event: any) => void,
    selected: string,
  ) {
    anotherFunctionInThePage(selected);
    onChange(selected);
  }

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <Test handleFunction={handlePrimaryFunction} input={input} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Am I passing `handlePrimaryFunction` incorrectly?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?
        <List
          Test={TestComponent}
        />
This is probably causing the problem.

Comment: You're not destructing your props in `TestComponent`. Replace `function TestComponent(handleFunction: any, input: any)` with 
`function TestComponent({handleFunction, input}: {handleFunction: any, input: any})` (Though your `any` types aren't offering you much except to avoid linting errors)